# Html.ActionLink in a loop causes unbreakable chain of <a> tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using this source code in a razor view:

```
@for( int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    <a href="action">link</a>
}
@for( int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("link", "action")
}
```

Produces two different blocks of html:

The first loop produces `<a>` tags with a line break between each:

```
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
<a href="action">link</a>
...
```

And the second one produces one long chain of `<a>` tags:

```
<a href="action">link</a><a href="action">link</a><a href="action">link</a><a href="action">link</a><a href="action">link</a><a href="action">link</a><a href="action">link</a>...
```

In the second case, browsers will not use any spacing between the links and will not allow the text to wrap if necessary creating one long non-breakable line of links. The fact that there is no space in the link text makes a difference. In my application, I'm really need a long list of one-word links and they have to wrap correctly.

What is the right way to use `Html.ActionLink` in this case?

I found two workarounds:

1. Wrap the `<a>` inside `<li>`
2. Use `<text></text>` after the `Html.ActionLink` call. That forces a line break in the generated source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a semantic point of view you're creating a bunch of links that form some kind of navigation. You should express that semantics in your generated HTML, so your so called work around with the <li> element is the "right" approach from a semantic point of view!

In HTML5 we have a tag to express that there is a bunch of links that forms some kind of navigation on your page:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    @for( int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
      @Html.ActionLink("link", "action")
    }
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you're using (X)HTML 4 you may consider to use a <div class="nav"> element instead.

Last point: Don't try to express some representation with your HTML code. The wrapping of HTML links is a representation thing. If you use semantic markup you may fix the representation too but that's not the reason to use semantic markup.

How you can use HTML 5 tags even with IE6 is demonstrated in [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/) link.

Comment: I agree with you, the semantic version is "better". I said the `<li>` is a workaround in the sense that I did not put it there with the intent of adding scemantic. I added it there to fix the behavior. Wrapping it in a `<span>` would also have been a workaround too. In the end, one has to use a "trick" to fix this Html.ActionLink() behavior. It's a good thing that one of those "tricks" gives semantic to the result.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve this problem:

```
@for( int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
     @Html.ActionLink("link", "action")
     @:&nbsp;
}
```